# How do I change the alt attribute on Microsoft Chart images?

Tags: asp.net, charts

Anyone know how to change the alt attribute on the MS Chart Control charts?

```
    Chart2.Attributes.Remove("alt");
    Chart2.Attributes["alt"] = "myAlt";
```

Doesn't work. It causes two alts , one empty and one `myAlt`.